# how to enalbe "Press ESC to exit full screen mode" in electron

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, electron, chromium

How can i enable the "Press ESC to exit full screen mode message" in **electron** while i'm in fullscreen in an iframe?

[image: 2019-11-06_13-01-16]

**Observation**: Same iframe with same options in Chrome shows the message, but electron doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be through some simple window controlling with the `remote` module.

```
const remote = require("electron").remote;

document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case "Escape":
            if (remote.getCurrentWindow().isFullScreen()) {
                remote.getCurrentWindow().setFullScreen(false);
            }
            break;
         }
});
```

**Code and original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37967762/10939275) by [Zen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5006372/zen)**.

Comment: My question was, how to enable the message in electron.
Not how to escape fullscreen mode.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you can't (at least not natively). That message is specific to Chrome and you would have to create a message like that yourself. For this, you would need to detect when the [`enter-html-full-screen`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#event-enter-html-full-screen) event fires and to display your own message when it does.